# FluentValidation and server+client remote validator

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, fluentvalidation

I am trying to build a generic remote validator extension for FluentValidation, similar to what is discussed in [this thread](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/discussions/258348). There is client-side solution posted in [this blog](http://nripendra-newa.blogspot.com/2011/05/fluent-validation-remote-validation.html), but I need the remote validator to work both client- and server-side.

The rule would look something like this:

```
IRuleBuilderOptions<T, TProperty> Remote(string action, 
                                         string controller, 
                                         Expression<Func<T, object>>[] properties, 
                                         IComparable[] values, 
                                         HttpVerbs httpVerb = HttpVerbs.Get);
```

Where:
`action` and `controller` are the names of the action/controller
`properties` is an array of model property expressions (m => m.FirstName)
`values` is an array of literal values

The setting up a rule for the validator may look something like this:

```
this.RuleFor(m => m.Username).Remote("UsernameUnique", "RemoteController", null, null);
```

I think I can figure out the client-side piece, as I will just build a jQuery adapter to invoke the action method, passing in the values.

What I can't figure out is how, from the `IsValid` method of the validator, to invoke the same controller action.

Here are some options I've considered:

- Somehow invoke the controller action remotely, creating a stub context. Not sure how to inject dependencies using IoC though. Service locators?
- Use a normal .NET method, and invoke that from both the validator and the action method.

I think this would be a powerful validator to have available, but it seems like any option I come up with will be ugly, even if I manage to get it working.

Are there better ways to tackle this? I'm totally open to anything that will work, I'm just not finding very many options, at least not elegant ones. But at this point, I would even be ok with a non-elegant solution, if there are no alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an additional method parameter that took in a lambda function for the Controller's action method.

It's sloppy, and I'm currently looking into ways to integrate the remote validation into the FluentValidation framework. I'll let you know if I come up with anything else.